# Swift skips one animation (UIView.animate)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a logoImage on a view, animating the constraints. 
The constraints animated are width and height ; going from original state of 220.0 to 240.0 (works fine) and THEN I would like to make it go back to 220.0 but the animation is skipped and the image goes directly back in 0.1second to 220.0.

Here is the code of the animation

```
func animate() {

        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 240.0
        self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 240.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                       delay:0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseIn,
                       animations:{

                        self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

            self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 220.0
            self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 220.0



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                           delay:0.0,
                           options: .curveEaseIn,
                           animations: {

                self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()

            })

        })

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help I could get! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `self.logoImage.setNeedsLayout()` within your completion block, before you re-set the constants. This since you need to invalidate the current layout of the receiver and trigger a layout update during the next update cycle.

Try this code instead and it will work for you:

```
func animate() {
    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 240.0
    self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 240.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                   delay:0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseIn,
                   animations:{

                    self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.logoImage.setNeedsLayout()
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 220.0
        self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 220.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay:0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseIn,
                       animations: {

            self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much ;)